# Linking Conio functions in Cygwin

Tags: c++, c, cygwin, dev-c++, conio

I am working on a shared lib that uses a third party library which uses calls to conio lib, when I try to build it using cygwin/g++ I get errors to undefined references to

```
__cprintf
__stricmp
__splithpath
etc..
```

I link my lib againts,

```
kernel32
wsock32
gdi32
```

which lib should i link so that those references are found?

PS. Third party lib I am using is built using Dev-Cpp

Answer (score 2):

That looks like code from an old Borland library.

`cprintf` can be directly replaced with `printf`.  It was an implementation of `printf` that printed directly to video memory in the DOS and OS/2 days.

`stricmp` is a case insensitive string compare.  Use `strcasecmp` instead.

I do not know of a replacement for splitpath in Cygwin/Linux.

You might be able to find an implementation of it in findutils.  You may also find a implementation of splitpath in the port of Turbovision to Linux or BSD.

With that said, `splitpath` on *nix like platforms should be nothing more than splitting the path string at the slashes (/) and verifying whether or not the last item in the path is a file/link/directory before setting the filename and extension parts of the path.